# Application Development Using Flex with SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, flex4

I want to build a demo app using SpringMVC as a backend and Flex as a fronend.
Can anyone please help me in this work.
My Questions:
1) Which tool I should use, where I can write code for both SpringMVC and Flex?
2) How to integrate this two different components?
3) I just want to build a Registration/Login demo. Please help me?

Note: I want to use free tools, plugins etc only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eclipse for both - just download the Flashbuilder plugin to allow you to develop Flex. Have a look at something like BlazeDS, which will allow you to call the spring MVC classes from Flex.

Comment: But Flashbuilder plugin is not available for free. Can you guide me to any document

Comment: A single Google search brought me to a legal page to get Flashbuilder for free for non-commercial use. I'm not going to do your research for you.

Comment: I am not saying you to do research for me. I said, if you come across any document then you can share that. But anyways thanks a lot.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Powerflasher's FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/), it is Eclipse based, last time I checked it has a free edition.  Like TrueDub says, BlazeDS is worth looking at, and there is also [Spring BlazeDS integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex/) you can take advantage too.